# Как считать аргументы в main из командной строки?

Tags: c++, c

Как считывать просто аргументы из argv я понимаю. А как считать допустим имена файлов и параметры по типу -l arg. Я увидела, что есть функция getopt, с помощью нее получаю аргументы после -l, а как потом считать имена файлов? В интернете нет особо инфы про эту функцию.

Comment: В когда в `argv[i]` будет `"-l"` в `argv[i+1]` будет путь к файлу...

Comment: [Вот тут](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html) прекрасно все описано (как и обычно в GNU документации)

Comment: [man 3 getopt](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html)

Comment: А в чём, собственно, затруднение? Для анализа аргументов из командной строки обычно используют конечный автомат. Т.е., цикл, в котором очередной прочитанный аргумент и текущее состояние определяют следующее состояние. Например, если текущее состояние "ожидается опция или аргумент", то при прочтении "-l" переходим в состояние "ожидается аргумент опции -l", и т.д...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> как потом считать имена файлов?

Вопрос не очень понятен, но рискну предположить что, Вы имеете в виду ситуацию типа:

```
progname -n4 -tNTFS report.txt
```

и Вы понимаете, как с помощью функции *getopt()* получить значения опций *-n* и *-t*.
Но не понимаете, как добраться до параметра *report.txt*.

Ситуация здесь такая же, как во многих языках программирования: параметры функции могут быть ключевые и могут быть позиционные. Ключевые различаются по именам (*-n* *-t*), а позиционные - по своей **позиции** - т.е. просто номеру места в списке параметров.

В языке командной строки принято (хотя и не обязательно), что позиционные параметры всегда идут после ключевых. Соответственно, если Вы прочтёте (как это уже Вам рекомендовали) *man 3 getopt*, то там об этом написано явно:

> If  there  are  no  more  option characters, getopt() returns -1.
> Then optind is the index in argv of the first argv-element that is not
> an option.

Т.е. когда при очередном вызове функции *getopt()* она вернёт -1, это сигнал о том, что ключевые параметры кончились и надо обрабатывать позициооные. При этом переменная *optind* будет иметь значение 3 и имя файла можне будет получить как-то так:

```
char buf[1024];
strncpy(buf, argv[optind], 1024);
```